# Smaller comment field as part of H&I review

Tags: bug, help-improvement

Is there a special reason that when you want to comment on a Help and Improvement review instigated edit you are only allowed 500 characters for the comment.

[image]

And then when you finish your edit, you can add a comment with 600 characters?

[image]

I haven't tried to edit a comment added during the review edit later on, to see if the restriction still exists then or that the 600 character limit applies. You can only try to do so within a few minutes and I was too late, and out of reviews for the day.

Comment: I'd guess it's the limit for edit summaries.

Comment: I expect this to be status-bydesign similar to [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/258861/158100)